# en construire X

Tags: pronoms

Bonjour,

> *Robert a eu l’idée de faire descendre les grandes boites de carton pour que les enfants s’amusent à les peindre ou à **en** construire des châteaux*.

Avant, dans le texte, je dis que des boites de carton se trouvent au grenier.

Je n'arrive pas à m'expliquer l'emploi de *en*, j'imagine qu'il remplace *à partir de* ou *avec*, *construire à partir de*, *construire sur la base de*, *construire avec*. Pourriez-vous me dire si c'est correct ?

Merci

Comment: Je pense que votre formulation est tout à fait correcte et votre explication également.

Comment: @LaurentS. L'explication repose sur la devinette alors qu'un minimum d'analyse grammaticale est nécessaire il me semble pour dépasser un savoir qui autrement ne sera qu'approximatif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Robert a eu l’idée de faire descendre les grandes boites de carton pour que les enfants s’amusent à les peindre ou à en construire des châteaux.

C'est une construction rare pour le verbe « construire ». Lorsque « en » est employé avec construire la relation n'est presque jamais celle qui est impliquée dans la présente phrase, c'est à dire, celle  correctement identifiée par les termes « à partir de », « avec », « sur la base de » ; la relation est précisément identifiée par la locution prépositive « au moyen de » (synonyme de « avec ») dans une construction courante de ce même verbe.

- construire au moyen de briques récupérées/au moyen de branches entrelacée/au moyen de boites/…

Dans la phrase, « en » est le pronom atone de la troisième personne (« atone » parce qu'il n'est pas possible de placer l'accent tonique dessus) ; la fonction grammaticale qu'il remplit dans sa proposition est celle de *complément circonstanciel*, dont on verra la sorte particulière ci-après. Si on pose la question « … pour que les enfants s'amusent à construire des châteaux au moyen de quoi ? » (qui n'est pas naturelle de prime abord mais qui inspirée par ce que l'on lit dans la phrase le devient) on doit répondre « construire des châteaux avec des boites, au moyen de boites » c'est à dire « construire des châteaux au moyen de « *en* » ». La fonction grammaticale de « en » est donc « complément circonstanciel de *moyen* du verbe « construire »».

Un examen des livres au moyen de la recherche « [en construire](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22en+construire%22&lr=lang_fr&safe=active&tbs=lr:lang_1fr&tbm=bks&ei=ZKzrX-qZJYyqa6aysMgK&start=300&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwjq24i6nfTtAhUM1RoKHSYZDKk4yAEQ8tMDCMsI&biw=1920&bih=968&dpr=1) » montre que c'est un usage rare pour « construire », ce qui tend à communiquer une fausse impression de non idiomaticité ; on s'aperçoit que sur plus de 200 cas il n'y en a peut-être pas plus de 5 ou 6 qui répondent à la catégorie « moyen ».

- ([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=oEHJBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA232&dq=%22en+construire%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjLkPCrpvTtAhWEyYUKHXVOCxwQ6AEwEnoECEMQAg#v=onepage&q=%22en%20construire%22&f=false)) J'ai apporté de grands cèdres des plus hauts sommets du Liban pour en construire ses colonnes.

Finalement, on se base sur le « rapport de recherche » fournit par le [TLFi, en² **I. A. 1. a.**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/en) pour constater que le moyen est bien inclus dans les possibilités.

> [Dans des constr. où « en » a valeur de compl. circ. il exprime] :
> [L'éloignement d'un lieu pour représenter un groupe nom. en fonction de compl. circ. : de là, de cet endroit, de + nom de lieu]
> [Employé avec certains verbes à la forme pronom., en partic. aller, avec un antécédent souvent tiré implicitement du contexte (cf. infra II B)]
> [Sans idée nette de point de départ]
> [L'origine, la source]
> [L'éloignement dans le temps (à mesure qu'on s'éloigne ou que l'on se rapproche de cette date s'en éloigner, en sortir)]
> [La cause (à la suite de, à cause de)]
> [Le moyen]
> [Le propos]

On remarque que la même phrase où « construire » a été remplacé par « faire » prend un accent de légitimité plus grand, on ne doute plus.

- Robert a eu l’idée de faire descendre les grandes boites de carton pour que les enfants s’amusent à les peindre ou à en faire des châteaux.

Ceci se comprend je crois du fait que l'expression du moyen avec « faire » est très courante.

Comment: Je vous remercie pour votre réponse et votre temps !

Answer (score 4):

Il n'y a pas de problème à l'écrire. Le sens est :

> ... pour que les enfants s'amusent à construire **des châteaux de boites de carton**.

comme, à partir de :

> Robert a eu l’idée de faire un grand tas de **sable** pour que les enfants s’amusent à le creuser ou à **en** construire **des châteaux**.

on peut écrire :

> ...ou à construire **[des châteaux de sable](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C3%A2teau_de_sable)**.

ou alors, si Robert a apporté des cartes à jouer :

> ...construire [**des châteaux de cartes**](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C3%A2teau_de_cartes).

« Châteaux en sable » ou « châteaux en cartes » ne sont pas idiomatiques.

Answer (score 3):

Comme l'illustre une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/44033/25619), *boîtes de carton* détermine les *châteaux*. Or le pronom *en* a vocation à remplacer un *[complément](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compl%C3%A9ment_(grammaire)) du nom*, entre [autres](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3513), d'où son emploi dans la phrase en question.

Comment: Je vous remercie, grâce à votre réponse, je comprends mieux la première réponse. Je n'étais pas sûre que « châteaux de boites de carton » soit correct.

Comment: Avec plaisir. Il est aussi possible d'employer la préposition [_en_](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/en#Pr%C3%A9position) (_boîtes en carton_). Voir aussi [ce lien](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=2167) pour pousser plus loin la réflexion. @Oreste

Comment: Rien ne dit que les boites de carton retiennent leur forme dans les constructions obtenues.

Comment: @LPH Rien ne dit qu'elles l'oublient...

Comment: Intéressant, bien généralement « les syntagmes servant de compléments de caractérisation [un complément du nom ; parmi les exemples : _une table en chêne_] [...] ne peuvent être représentés par _en_. » (LBU14§348cR4 ; §676b) mais... « certains compléments introduits par _de_ ne peuvent être représentés par _en_ [...] C'est le cas des compléments de manière [...] » (LBU14§676a2). Seul le pseudo-complément ferait « exception à la règle selon laquelle _dont_  (§ 724, c) et _en_ (§ 676, c) ne peuvent représenter un syntagme qui lui-même dépend d'un nom introduit par une préposition » (LBU14§348b).

Comment: Il y a là matière à réflexion...

Comment: Vous avez raison, je pensais que la discussion avait été terminée. J'attendrai davantage à l'avenir.

Comment: Mais quoi que ce soit on vote selon ce que l'on pense et non selon ce qu'en pensent les autres, non ?

Comment: @Oreste Tout à fait !