# Nature et fonction grammaticale de « boîtes de carton » dans « les enfants s'amusent à construire des châteaux de boîtes de carton » ?

Tags: grammaire, pluriel, groupe-nominal, groupe-verbal

Dans une [autre question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/44032/25619) on présente une phrase que j'adapte comme suit :

> Les enfants s'amusent à construire des châteaux de boîtes de
> carton.

Quelle serait la nature et la(les) fonction(s) grammaticale(s) possibles de « boîtes de carton » dans la phrase et pourquoi ? Le singulier (pluriel : *boîtes*) changerait-t-il l'analyse ? Incidemment la [nouvelle](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=4333) [grammaire](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=5463) apporte-t-elle un éclairage supplémentaire sur la qualification ?

Answer (score 1):

La fonction grammaticale est tout simplement « complément du nom « château »», mais comme « château de boite(s) de carton »  n'est pas défini, on ne peut pas aller plus loin et définir la nature de ce complément de nom. On le peut pour des phrases nominales définies comme par exemple « château de cartes », château de sable », « château de Bohème », ou pour des constructions évidentes (château de briques, château de pierre, de verre,…) ;
D'après le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de) « de » prend une valeur sémantique en corrélation avec celle du mot subséquent ». Il n'est pas possible d'attribuer une valeur sémantique à « de  » dans « château de  boite(s) de carton » ; (c'est fait avec du carton de  boite de carton ? des boites de carton ?). Il est possible de faire cela pour « château de cartes »,  « château de sable » et « château de Bohême », (complément de nom exprimant le moyen, la matière, et la sorte, respectivement).

*Addition prompted by comment from **[user 20goto10](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/25619/20goto10)***

Il s'agit bien de châteaux mais on verra que même cela n'est pas nécessaire. De plus, il n'est pas nécessaire dans tous les cas, en utilisant un nom, d'ajouter les qualificatifs et compléments qui vont servir à déterminer de quelle sorte particulière on parle, et d'ailleurs, faire cela complètement n'est jamais possible : on doit se contenter d'une approximation raisonnable qui suffit à la compréhension. La pratique courante consiste à utiliser un syntagme assez complet lorsque le concept est introduit dans le discours puis à utiliser par la suite une abréviation de celui-ci (Je crois que je ne devrais pas avoir à vous rappeler ça.).

- Elle voulait une poupée qui fait non et qui bat des cils. On est allé faire les magasins pour trouver une poupée, ce qui n'a pas été facile. Maintenant, la poupée ne l'intéresse plus et elle veut une dinette. (*Il s'agit toujours de cette poupée  qui fait non et qui bat des cils, et qui a été achetée récemment.*)

Dans le cas présent il n'y a pas de problème puisque le contexte indique clairement que ce sont des modèles miniature d'une sorte ou d'une autre et pour le jeux des enfants (ça suffit comme information globale).

Non, je ne veux pas dire « ambigu ».  Lorsque l'on parle de châteaux de cartes, nous savons tous que cela consiste de constructions qui ne sont pas réellement des châteaux — On voit bien là que la définition permet de reconnaitre une locution nominale comme légitime sans même que le nom utilisé réponde à la définition de ce qu'il décrit vraiment — et qui sont faites en posant des cartes sur des cartes, on a dans l'esprit des images qui les représentent (tout lecteur francophone et d'autres) et on doit pouvoir trouver dans des dictionnaires une définition qui explique exactement cela. Il en est de même pour les châteaux de sables : on sait que ce sont des modèles de châteaux qui sont fabriqués en sable mouillé. Dans le cas de « châteaux de boites de cartons », à moins que je ne me trompe, ce type de construction ne peut pas être connue au delà d'une localité ou peut-être même d'une famille et pour le reste du monde cela n'a pas beaucoup de sens et ça ne peut au plus  lui dire que ceci : c'est quelque chose qu'il ne connait pas, et par le biais du contexte dans lequel on trouve le terme, il s'agit sûrement d'une construction de modèles miniatures dans laquelle des boites en cartons sont utilisées. Comment elles sont utilisées n'est pas évident. Il n'y a pas d'indéfinition de termes dans la phrase dont l'idée est tirée (recopiée ci-dessus).

- Robert a eu l’idée de faire descendre les grandes boites de carton pour que les enfants s’amusent à les peindre ou à en construire des châteaux.

Considérant la question sous l'angle d'un principe moderne reconnu (que l'on tient de Frege), la compositionalité, la locution « des châteaux de boite(s) de carton » n'est pas définie. Il n'est pas question d'ambiguïté mais d'indéfinition.

Dire que l'on construit des châteaux au moyen de boites de carton est une communication qui ne comprends aucune inconnue linguistique ; on n'est aucunement tenu de dire comment la construction est faite.

Avant que le terme « château de boite(s) de carton » ait été reconnu le scripteur doit utiliser des guillemets, fournir des explications, jusqu'au jour où le terme a été diffusé suffisamment pour que l'on puisse dire qu'il est passé dans le langage ;   alors, pour la plupart, les lecteurs et locuteurs savent ce qui est  représenté.

La virgule ne change rien et on l'utilisera par exemple si l'on parle de plusieurs matières, mais on ne sépare jamais un nom de son complément prépositionnel unique par une virgule.

- …construire des châteaux de balsa, de bois, de liège,…

Ici  « de » peut *prendre une valeur sémantique en corrélation avec « balsa », « bois », « liège », etc.* puisque ces noms décrivent des matières et qu'il existe une connexion entre château et matière en cela  qu'un château qui est pratiquement toujours en pierre peut quand même être en pierre d'une sorte particulière et dans des métaphores pratiquement n'importe quelle matière.

- Les cannons de l'envahisseur étaient si puissants que les forteresses qu'ils détruisirent paraissaient des châteaux de sucre.

Cependant, considérant « château de boite(s) de carton » on ne peut pas conclure que des boites sont une matière ; il n'y a pas de corrélation évidente en rapport avec « boite » ; il y en a une avec « carton » sans aucun doute et pour cette même raison « boite de carton » est défini, mais on ne parle pas de château de carton dans cette phrase. Alors qu'il existe une possibilité d'exprimer le moyen par l'intermédiaire de la préposition « de » lorsqu'il s'agit de verbes (en particulier « construire »), et on parle alors de complément circonstanciel de moyen,  il n'y en a pas pour les noms, et les compléments de nom exprimant le moyen ne se trouvent pas ; ceci se vérifie dans la partie « [**I.B.6.**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de) » de l'entrée « de¹, préposition » dans le TLFi.

> - 6. [La condition préalable est un moyen à partir duquel une chose a ou peut avoir lieu] « De » marque le moyen, l'instrument ou l'intermédiaire. Il signifie « à l'aide de » et entre en concurrence avec « **par** » et « **avec** ».

- Il l'a construit de ses mains  (*les mains sont le moyen*) — <s>C'est une construction de ses mains</s> (*Dans cette seconde syntaxe on a l'impression que les mains sont construites, et ce n'est pas de cela qu'il s'agit.*)

Il y a cependant  une correspondence pour la matière.

- Ce bâti est construit de bois. C'est une construction de/en bois.

Donc, l'ajout d'une virgule n'a aucun effet, sinon de rendre les choses plus difficiles à comprendre ; ce qui compte ce sont les relations qui se dégagent du contexte parce qu'elles sont trouvées habituelles (définition) ou  parce que le contexte les rend très plausibles (corrélation).

Non, justement, je crois que ce n'est pas relié à l'autre question et qu'il y dans la réponse de laquelle vous tirez votre inspiration un biais  dû à cet enchevêtrement de pronoms, prépositions correspondantes et relations diverses. Dans l'autre question on est concerné par un pronom, « en ». En tant que pronom il doit  avoir la fonction grammaticale d'un nom ; ce n'est ni le sujet de « construire » (qui est « les enfants », ni le complément d'objet direct (qui est « des châteaux ») ; on voit aussi que ce n'est pas un COI ; c'est donc un complément circonstanciel du verbe « construire ». Reprenons  cette phrase et examinons la un peu différemment ; en gros elle dit
« …pour que les enfants s'amusent à les peindre ou à construire des châteaux » : on a éliminé « en » de cette approximation et on voit que l'on dit essentiellement la même chose, mais il y a rarement des mots gratuits dans une phrase et donc on doit se soucier de ce que « en » apporte. L'analyse préliminaire indique qu'il s'agit d'un complément circonstanciel ; on peut donc se pencher sur l'entrée de « en » au TLFi dans la partie qui traite de ces compléments et on peut poser les questions habituelles qui concernent ces compléments (construire quand ? …comment ? …en quoi ? ……où ? …de quelle manière ?…). On voit dans la partie des compléments qu'il n'y a pas toutes les possibilités : par exemple, avec « en », dans cette construction, on ne peut pas exprimer la manière. On voit plus ou moins vite qu'il s'agit du moyen (qui figure dans la liste). Ceci est détaillé dans ma réponse à cette [autre question](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/44044/17649).

Il se trouve qu'il n'existe pas de possibilité d'expression du moyen en utilisant « de » soit en tant que préposition introduisant un complément de nom (autrement appelé « complément déterminatif »).

Passer de « *pour que les enfants s'amusent  à  en construire des châteaux* » à « *pour que les enfants s'amusent à construire des châteaux de boites de carton* » revient à transformer l'expression d'un moyen en l'expression de quelque chose qui reste indéterminé parce que « de » n'exprime pas le moyen dans cette locution nominale ; en fait il n'exprime rien que l'on puisse reconnaitre et a seulement un vague air de familiarité.

Cependant « *pour que les enfants s'amusent à construire des châteaux au moyen de boites de carton* » est correct ; cela est en accord avec ce que la personne qui pose la question suggère :  « j'imagine qu'il remplace **à partir de** ou **avec**, **construire à partir de**, construire sur la base de, **construire avec** ». « Avec » est un synonyme de « au moyen de ».

On doit dire que pour un usage local il existe une définition intrinsèque : dans une famille tous les membres connaitront la locution et elle fera office de terme valide dans la famille ; cependant cela n'est pas le langage que l'on discute.

Bien que « fruit à noyau » soit semble devoir sa définition à la compositionalité, il n'en est pas ainsi. On en trouve une définition.

> I. − BOT. Matière dure et ligneuse de l'endocarpe, se trouvant au milieu de certains fruits, qui enveloppe l'amande ou les amandes. Il y a huit espèces de péricarpes. 1° Le fruit à pépins (...) 2° Le fruit à noyau (cerises, prunes...) (Baudrillart,Nouv. manuel forest., t.1, 1808, p.62)

L'ubiquité des fruits à noyau et le savoir courant que dans certains fruit il y a un noyau ne doit pas être confondu avec une corrélation. Ceci se retrouve dans « roulement à billes », dont les référents sont beaucoup moins exposés dans l'existence de tous les jours ; il devient plus réel encore qu'une définition est nécessaire, il me semble.

Comment: Merci ! _Pas défini_, tu veux dire ambigu ? Possiblement. Mais _construire des chatêaux, de boîtes de carton_ avec une virgule disons, bien je ne sais pas si c'est plus clair et est-ce que l'on construit vraiment « un château ». Évidemment c'est relié aussi à l'autre question mais l'emploi de la préposition dans exemples que tu présentes n'est pas tant _défini_ que les locutions sont elles figées dans certains cas, une notion différente. Je ne sais pas si c'est un bon exemple mais dans _fruit à noyau_ la relation n'est pas nécessairement évidente au départ mais c'est ainsi que ça s'exprime...

Comment: @20goto10 Pour vraiment apporter toute les précisions qui peuvent être utile à la compréhension des réponses il a fallu de très nombreuses lignes ; donc j'ai fait passé le texte de la réponse à ce premier commentaire dans la réponse originale. Je n'ai pas hésité sur la longueur puisque on peut toujours laisser tomber lorsque on ne voit aucun intérêt à éplucher des lignes et des lignes.

Comment: On salue l'effort. Merci !

Answer (score 0):

> Quelle serait la nature et la(les) fonction(s) grammaticale(s) possibles de « boîtes de carton » dans la phrase et pourquoi ?

Nom (boîtes) suivi d'un complément, groupe prépositionnel indiquant la matière (de carton). Le tout étant lui-même aussi un autre complément du nom « chateaux », groupe prépositionnel indiquant de quoi ils sont faits.

J'aurais pu écrire « de boîtes **en** carton ».

> Le singulier (pluriel : boîtes) changerait-t-il l'analyse ?

J'aurais du mal à utiliser le singulier car il est difficile de considérer « boîte en carton » comme indénombrable.

Comment: Merci ! Quel est le nom du type de complément/groupe prépositionel indiquant _la matière_ ? Si je mets _château_ au singulier et que c'est un très jeune enfant, et que j'ai mentionné avoir reçu mon nouveau réfrigérateur dans la dernière phrase, l'aspect dénombrable est-il encore un obstacle ? En fait que veux-tu dire par là au juste ?